# Python accessing parent class variable as instant variable in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, instance-variables, class-variables

I'm trying to access instance variables of a parent class as class variables in a child class.

The purpose is that the parent class will have a lot of child classes which all need to have the same structure, and a lot of different people will be working with and creating these child classes, without needing to know the inner workings of the parent class.
Here's my example:

```
class Human(ABC):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.human_name = args[0]
        cls.source = f'database_{cls.__name__}'.lower()
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def query(self):
        pass


class Company:
    class Employee(Human):
        query = f'SELECT {human_name} FROM {source};'

        # these two functions are just for testing and will not be in the final product
        def print_something(self):
            print(self.human_name)

        def print_source(self):
            print(self.source)


e = Company.Employee('John')
print(e.human_name)
print(e.query)
e.print_source()
```

I want to be able to create a child class of parent class Human (structured together in Company) where I only need to define the query variable which should automatically recognise the variables `human_name` and `source`.

How would I go about making this as simple as possible? Is this even possible?
Many thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect nesting `Employee` in `Company` to do. In any case, you say that you want to access class variables from the parent class as instance variables, but that works fine (assuming you implement the abstract property...). The problem is accessing instance variables from the class definition, but in your case, no instance has been created yet, and strangely, the creation of your class variables depends on instantiation of an instance.... and the only way to reference them there is to do it directly. But I don't see why it is necessary to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The structuring of `Employee` in `Company` is mostly to keep everything structured. In `Company` there will come child classes of `Human` like `Boss`, `HR`, `Catering` etc, while there could become something like `SportsClub` in the future too which will then has inner classes like `Trainer`, `Member`, ... If that makes sense. All those `Human` child classes need only their own specific query.


How would I go about implementing the abstract property of the variables defined in `__new__` ? I can't seem to access those variables.

Comment: That generally is not how classes are meant to be used.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your feedback! I want the `Human` child classes to be as simple as possible, without much extra functions or requirements (hence using `__new__` instead of `__init__` in the parent class)
But I will look into other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How is using `__new__` instead of `__init__` keeping things simple?

Comment: Because I don't need to have an `__init__` calling the `super()` in the `Employee` class, no?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to if you implemented `__init__` in the parent class, why would you need an `__init__` calling `super()` in the `Employee`. Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it but must've done something wrong as it now works. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to actually implement the property.

```
class Human(ABC):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.human_name = args[0]
        cls.source = f'database_{cls.__name__}'.lower()
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def query(self):
        pass


class Company:
    class Employee(Human):
        @property
        def query(self):
            return f'SELECT {self.human_name} FROM {self.source};'

        # these two functions are just for testing and will not be in the final product
        def print_something(self):
            print(self.human_name)

        def print_source(self):
            print(self.source)


e = Company.Employee('John')
print(e.human_name)
print(e.query)
e.print_source()
```

Note, however, since `__new__` creates class variables... this query will always be the same across instances:

```
employee1 = Company.Employee('John')
employee2 = Company.Employee('Jack')

print(employee1.query)
print(employee2.query)
```

will print:

```
SELECT Jack FROM database_employee;
SELECT Jack FROM database_employee;
```

Comment: Gotcha! I tried omitting using a function (implementing the property) but it seems impossible to do so. Thank you!